# In a list of lists, i need to limit the elements in each individual list to first 100

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists of texts. The number of elements in an individual list should not exceed 100.

Example list-
 `doc_sentence= [[abc, def, efg,........,cba,cab,zxy(100 plus items)],[bgasd,tgeasddc,iudcuic,usvu,... (100+ items)],[cnio, jdnciown, iowcin, .... (100+ items)], .... [....]]`

I need to store these lists as individual lists of not more than 100 elements in it. These individual lists can be stored as 1st element name.
`abc = [abc, def, efg,........100th]`
`bgasd = [bgasd,tgeasddc,iudcuic,usvu,...100th element]`

I have written below for extracting 100 elemnts from each list from the list of lists-

```
truncated_sentence = []
for i, value in enumerate(doc_sentence):
          if i =100:
             break
          truncated_sentence.append(doc_sentence)
```

However, I am not getting correct results. Is there a better and efficient way to do this?

Comment: ```[data[:100] for data in doc_sentence]```

Comment: @SreeramTP For storing each lists individually, I have used the same code to extract the 1st element from the list. names = [x[0]for x in doc_sentence] Now i have a list of names that can be used as a variable to store the individual list. Can you please guide me on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 truncated_sentence = [x[:100] for x in doc_sentence]
```

Comment: For storing each lists individually, I have used the same code to extract the 1st element from the list.

names = [x[0]for x in doc_sentence]

Now i have a list of names that can be used as a variable to store the individual list. Can you please guide me through the next steps?